# proving a certain function is convex

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

Consider $n$  variable  points points $ z_1,z_2,...,z_n$ in the
closed disc $x^2+y^2 \leq 1.$ Now consider the total  pairwise  distance  between them  to be:
$$ d(n)= \sum_{\substack{1 \leq i <j \leq n}} |z_i-z_j|  .$$
I want to show  that $ d(n)$ is a convex function from $\mathbb R^{2n}\to \mathbb R$  ,considered as a function of the vector $ (z_1,z_2,.,z_n)$, for a given arbitrary  $n>2$ Now ,if we recall the definition of convexity,we have: 
 ** Definition**A function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is said to be convex if, for any two points $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and any $0 \leq t \leq 1$, we have:

$$f(t\mathbf{x} + (1-t)\mathbf{y}) \leq tf(\mathbf{x}) + (1-t)f(\mathbf{y}).$$ Of course we can go as:To show that $d_{av}(n)$ is a convex function of the vector $(z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_n)$  we need to show that for any two vectors $(z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_n)$ and $(w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_n)$  any $t \in [0,1]$, we have:

$$d(n, t(z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_n) + (1-t)(w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_n)) \leq td(n,z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_n) + (1-t)d(n,w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_n)$$

where $d(n,z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_n)$ is the total pairwise distance between the points $z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_n$ in the closed disc.

For simplicity, let us write $z_i = x_i + iy_i$ and $w_i = u_i + iv_i$ for all $i$. Then, we have:

\begin{align*}
d(n, t(z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_n) &+ (1-t)(w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_n)) \\
&= \sum_{\substack{1 \leq i <j \leq n}} \operatorname{dist}(tz_i + (1-t)w_i, tz_j + (1-t)w_j) \\
&= \sum_{\substack{1 \leq i <j \leq n}}|t(z_i - z_j) + (1-t)(w_i - w_j)| \\
&\leq \sum_{\substack{1 \leq i <j \leq n}}(t|z_i - z_j| + (1-t)|w_i - w_j|) \\
&= t\sum_{\substack{1 \leq i <j \leq n}}|z_i - z_j| + (1-t)\sum_{\substack{1 \leq i <j \leq n}}|w_i - w_j| \\
&= td(n,z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_n) + (1-t)d(n,w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_n)
\end{align*}

where the inequality follows from the triangle inequality for complex numbers.Does that establish $d_{av}$ is convex or is my approach mistaken?Or,could we settle  by just  arguing  that the Euclidean distance is a convex function and that the sum of convex function is a convex function?

Comment: I am not sure that I see a connection to statistics. Might this be a question for Math Stack Exchange?

Comment: *“the Euclidean distance is a convex function and that the sum of convex function is a convex function”* – that is correct. See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4299509/42969 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1370235/42969.